# Gitlab CI Predefined variable ${CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA} sometime returns strange output

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I wanted to check for changed files between previous commit occurs and latest commit with

```
git diff ${CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA} ${CI_COMMIT_SHA} --name-only
```

For official documentation about

> **${CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA}** : The previous latest commit present on a
> branch. Is always 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 in
> pipelines for merge requests.

So from my assumption, when there are some changes but no merge request occur, that `${CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA}` shouldn't be 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000. However, recently I've tested with this following .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - info
  - deploy

variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
  GIT_CHECKOUT: "true"

information:
  stage: info
  script:
    - echo ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
    - echo ${CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA}
    - echo ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
    - export CHANGES=`git diff ${CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA} ${CI_COMMIT_SHA} --name-only`
    - echo ${CHANGES}
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "test"
  tags:
    - master
```

Some scenarios

1. Update .gitlab-ci.yml itself, the `${CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA}` was not equal all zero (correct)
2. Create text file and add some contents via Gitlab UI
   Here's where the issue occurred

   - first edit: After running the pipeline `${CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA}` was not equal all zero (correct) and `${CI_COMMIT_SHA}` was changed to a new number.
   - second edit: `${CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA}` was changed to all zero !? and `${CI_COMMIT_SHA}` remain the same as the previous one.

from the second attempt, I just only added words in same text file, No merge occur.
Why did the `${CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA}` behave like this? I also see this kind of behavior in other project. Isn't it weird? or it's my misunderstanding ?

Here's the output from Gitlab's runner panel

1. First edit

```
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
$ echo ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
test
$ echo ${CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA}
02c9b473c269ff69f54eac42fd5d1c4ace98888e
$ echo ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
c3d04bd751d4199aa6f2a5c43f3da55100ce42a3
$ export CHANGES=`git diff ${CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA} ${CI_COMMIT_SHA} --name-only`
$ echo ${CHANGES}
test.txt
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

2. Second edit

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ echo ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
test
$ echo ${CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA}
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
$ echo ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
62f73dcf2ae8672752fa1ace7a77b97d33ee49df
$ export CHANGES=`git diff ${CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA} ${CI_COMMIT_SHA} --name-only`
fatal: bad object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
$ echo ${CHANGES}
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look to the documentation page of variables:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

Then you will see that `CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` and `CI_COMMIT_SHA` are always `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` in pipelines for merge requests.

That is probably the problem you are facing.

You can create your own variables:

```sh
export COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA="$(git rev-parse HEAD~1)"
export COMMIT_SHA="$(git rev-parse HEAD~0)"
```

So the example will look like:

```yaml
stages:
  - info
  - deploy

variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
  GIT_CHECKOUT: "true"

information:
  stage: info
  script:
    - export COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA="$(git rev-parse HEAD~1)"
    - export COMMIT_SHA="$(git rev-parse HEAD~0)"
    - echo "${COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA}"
    - echo "${COMMIT_SHA}"
    - export CHANGES="`git diff "${COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA}" "${COMMIT_SHA}" --name-only`"
    - echo "${CHANGES}"
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "test"
  tags:
    - master
```

Comment: `git rev-parse HEAD~1` will don't always be equal to `CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA`, for instance when you push several commits at once

Comment: I have a case where `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` is `merge_request_event` and `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_EVENT_TYPE` is `merge_train`, but `CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` is populated with a nonzero SHA. Also `CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` and `CI_COMMIT_SHA` are equal.

Answer (score 3):

From my own tests, I see `CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` be `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` when I push a new branch (with `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE`  being `push`)

As of today (March 2022), the documentation does not list all the cases where `CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA`== `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

[image]

Comment: CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA is also 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for push pipelines for tags (e.g. on the main branch)