# Gitlab Pipeline | CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA is zero in case of $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE = "web"

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, nrwl-nx

Trying to retrieve latest commit in main branch before the new head.

But using `CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` its returning always zero's. In case, if I run pipeline from the GitLab UI.

It working fine if its trigged automatically in case of a push to main branch.

Pipline Custome Variables using [Predefined Gitlab CI variables:](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)--

- NX_HEAD=$CI_COMMIT_SHA
- NX_BASE=${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DIFF_BASE_SHA:-$CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA}

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug in whatever tool you are using. All-zeros mean "this ref does not exist yet / any-more and should not be used".

Comment: When I create a new pipeline through the api, it also stays at 0.

Comment: What are you expecting the value to be for pipelines that run from anything other than a push? What is "before the new head" in these cases?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is related to [issue 12850](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/12850) "`CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` is all zero in a merge request pipeline".
Or [issue 28252](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/28252) "Expose `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_SHA` and `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_SHA` in detached merge request pipelines"

Try a simple test to see if that would work better with your current version of GitLab:

```yaml
image: node:8

test-ci-vars:
  only:
    - master
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - echo CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
    - echo CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_SHA=${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_SHA}
    - echo CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_SHA=${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_SHA}
    - echo CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME=${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME}
    - echo CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME=${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}
```

Comment: In Case of merge request CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA expected to be zero also mentioned in the documentation but I'm trying to access when running pipeline from gitlab ui against main branch.

Comment: @user1264429 So, not a new branch, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71601191/6309)?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your pipeline is inspired by [Configuring CI Using GitLab and Nx](https://nx.dev/recipes/ci/monorepo-ci-gitlab).

If so, you might have set `GIT_DEPTH` to `0` which according to [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#limit-the-number-of-changes-fetched-during-clone) should disable the shallow cloning. Unfortunately, it looks like this doesn't work as expected, see [issues 292470](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/292470).

Therefore, maybe you'd like to change

```yaml
variables:
  GIT_DEPTH: 0
```

to

```yaml
variables:
  GIT_DEPTH: 100
```

so that the last 100 commits (instead of [the default](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#limit-the-number-of-changes-fetched-during-clone)) are available, which then hopefully will result in `$CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` being defined in a non-MR pipeline.

[This blog](https://medium.com/@liorbaber/deploy-affected-app-with-nx-and-gitlab-28a5b16986e3) might also be interesting.